# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'delete' on 'IDBObjectStore': The transaction is not active

Tags: reactjs, indexeddb, tensorflow.js

I am getting this error when I am trying to save  my tensorflowjs model in IndexedDb. Basically I am working on an offline webapp which can predict emotions in real time. To make my app faster, I have to use Indexed Db. The front end is in Reactjs.
The error comes in this line:

`await this.model.save('indexeddb://' + INDEXEDDB_KEY);`

Here is the code.

```
  try {
    this.model = await tf.loadLayersModel('indexeddb://' + INDEXEDDB_KEY);

    // Safe to assume tensorflowjs database and related object store exists.
    // Get the date when the model was saved.
    try {
      const db = await openDB(INDEXEDDB_DB, 1, );
      const item = await db.transaction(INDEXEDDB_STORE)
                           .objectStore(INDEXEDDB_STORE)
                           .get(INDEXEDDB_KEY);
      const dateSaved = new Date(item.modelArtifactsInfo.dateSaved);
      await this.getModelInfo();
      console.log(this.modelLastUpdated);
      if (!this.modelLastUpdated  || dateSaved >= new Date(this.modelLastUpdated).getTime()) {
        console.log('Using saved model');
      }
      else {
        this.setState({
          modelUpdateAvailable: true,
          showModelUpdateAlert: true,
        });
      }

    }
    catch (error) {
      console.warn(error);
      console.warn('Could not retrieve when model was saved.');
    }

  }
  // If error here, assume that the object store doesn't exist and the model currently isn't
  // saved in IndexedDB.
  catch (error) {
    console.log('Not found in IndexedDB. Loading and saving...');
    console.log(error);

    this.model = await tf.loadLayersModel(MODEL_PATH);
    console.log(this.model,"model")
    await this.model.save('indexeddb://' + INDEXEDDB_KEY);
  }
}
// If no IndexedDB, then just download like normal.
else {
  console.warn('IndexedDB not supported.');
  this.model = await tf.loadLayersModel(MODEL_PATH);
}

this.setState({ modelLoaded: true });


// Warm up model.
// let prediction = tf.tidy(() => this.model.predict(tf.zeros([1, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3])));
// prediction.dispose();
```

}

'''

Answer (score 1):

a transaction closes if no requests pending. looks like your awaits are doing some non-indexeddb stuff, and so naturally, because you do not immediately queue up some requests on the transaction, it closes, and then when you do eventually later request something on the transaction, it is closed by that time (inactive).

start your transaction after you do the other async stuff. do not do async stuff in between starting a transaction and adding requests to it.